# Change contents background color in UIWebView in Xcode

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webview

I create a simple `UIWebview` control in which I load the contents from a html file, but I want to change the background of that html page not my web view.

Do have any idea about this?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Modify the HTML to use the background color of your choice
2. Add a javascript function to the HTML that sets the background color to whatever it is passed, and then call it by using [`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW21)

Example JS function:

```
function changeBackground(color){
document.getElementByName("body").style.background="#"+color;
}
```

Example ios calling code:

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"changeBackground(\"%@\");",yourColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `UIWebView` background color and opaque:NO

```
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

[webView setOpaque:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set background color at html body.